# Jenkins pipeline mvn Package command not working

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-plugins

My test is working fine as Maven project. It fetches code from Git.

I wanted to execute the same in Pipeline so I wrote the below script for pipeline project.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Getting the project from GIT') {
            steps {
               echo 'Pulling..';
                git branch: 'main',
                url: 'https://github.com/user/project.git';
            }
        }
        
    stage('Cleaning the project') {
             
            steps {
                echo 'cleaning project ...'
                sh 'mvn clean'
            }
        }
        
    stage('Artifact Construction') {
             
            steps {
                echo "artificat contruction"
                sh 'mvn package'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I execute , the third stage seems not to work.

[image]

Console output:
[image]

[image]

Maven configuration :

[image]

This is the version of Maven

[image]

I tried everything to solve this issue, can you guys help me? Is it a maven version problem?

Comment: That’s a very old version of maven!

Comment: Yes, very old. Consider latest moving to latest. But if you want help, post as text the logs screenshots, and post your pom section relating to the error. The other screenshots not relevant.

Comment: The error message told requires maven 3.1.0, but your maven is 3.0.5.

Comment: Hey guys I just fixed it by configuring my pom.xml thank you @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: @CompteGmail please provide details so others may benefit from your work if they have the same problem

Comment: @CompteGmail, I too would like to know how "configuring the pom" addressed the stated error "The plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0 requires Maven version 3.1.0". Did you use a lower version of the plugin that is compatible with apache-maven:3.0.5 (2013-02-23) and if so, why?

Comment: Hey @IanW I can email you my pom.xml if you want, sorry for being this late!

Comment: S/O is a public forum for sharing knowledge. Post your fixes to the pom.xml as an answer (leaving the accepted answer as-is), with an explanation of how that solved your problem. Or update your post to include the before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running maven version - 3.0.5.
Maven resource plugin -3.2.0 is not compatible with this version of maven.

Upgrade maven installation to higher version. You can refer below plugin documentation page:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-resources-plugin-3.2.0/plugin-info.html